# What is an appropriate location to setup a Git repo on an OSX server?

Tags: macos, git

I am setting up an OSX Git server and I am wondering if there is a standard location to set this up? I do NOT want to have a single git user that everyone uses to checkin, and as such there doesn't seem to be any shared directories to put it in like windows has. I could create a git user and store the repo in there directories, and then give permission to the users that need access, but this seems a little hackey...

Comment: Isn't `/Users/Shared` already on every Mac OS X machine for that purpose?

Comment: I had initially thought of that folder, but when I had two users viewing it at the same time in a terminal there were permission issues when one tried to delete a file inside of it. I would like to use it, I just want to make sure that is an appropriate place.

Comment: Well, anyplace is appropriate, really.  You're going to need to do some permissions wrangling anyway.

Comment: Surely better here to set up a git server so no file sharing just via the git: protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't want the root user to own the directories, so I think you're correct in your intuition that a 'git' user is correct, and not actually hackey at all.  This directory will have lax permissions anyway, so your other allowed users can push changes to the repository.

So a specific user:

1) Let's you easily keep everything related to the repo in a clear, "namespaced" location.
2) Since you're using OSX (why not Ubuntu, by the way? it's a bit more set up to do this out of the box), you should just live with its idiosyncrasies and use the Users folder, inside that you can put a "projects" or "source" or "repository" folder, whatever suits your fancy.

Just 2 cents, this will be slightly more challenging on OSX to get all set up, Apple's UNIX setup isn't entirely straightforward in many ways if you're used to Debian / RH / etc.

Comment: It has to be OSX - I am getting automated iOS builds going.